# Regex C++ Pattern Aide

Tags: c++, regex

I'm just starting C++ out here and trying to use a very basic regex pattern. Here's what I have:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string choice;
    std::regex pattern3 ("\d");

    std::cout << "Enter " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice;

    if (std::regex_match(choice, std::regex((pattern3)))) 
    {
        std::cout << "works" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to enter a single digit and it does not work. I searched high and low and all I could find was posts about gcc not being up to date with regex, but those are from at least a couple of years back. I am getting no return for works, even with the simplest form.

Comment: You need to escape those backslashes (e.g. `"\\d"`) or use a raw string literal (e.g. `R"(\d)")`.  The latter makes the regex easier to read.

Comment: Don't spam, tags! C is not C++ is not C.